# Prolog family tree same generation rules

Tags: prolog, predicate, rule

I am taking a programing class and it was c++ for the majority and we spent a few classes on Prolog and the instructor told us to research on our own which is what I've been doing.  I've been playing around with a Family tree program and I'm having trouble with the rules for same_generation.  Same generation would essentially be a sibling or a cousin.  With the way I have it now,

if I query:

```
 same_generation(jill,X).
```

I get:

```
false.
```

If I query:

```
 same_generation(jack, X).
```

I get:

```
X=jack
X=phil
```

which is correct but, jill is also the same generation.

Any help on where I'm going wrong with that rule would be greatly appreciated!  Below is the "family tree" and my code.

[image: Family Tree]

I'm just going to leave the rules and take out most of the facts to condense the post...

```
mother(lisa,abe). ....

father(tony,abe). ....


parent(X,Y) :-mother(X,Y).
parent(X,Y) :-father(X,Y).

sibling(X,Y) :- father(P,X), father(P,Y), mother(Q,X), mother(Q,Y).

cousin(X,Y) :-parent(A,X), parent(B,Y), sibling(A,B).

same_generation(X,Y) :- sibling(Someone,P), cousin(Someone,X), cousin(P,Y).
```

Comment: Jill and Jack are second cousins. You only consider siblings and first cousins. Therefor it doesn't find Jack and Jill as same_generation.

Comment: What do the directed edges represent?

Comment: Maybe you could define `same_generation` as "having a common ancestor N levels above". Something with `ancestor(X,Y,N)` where X is an ancestor of Y with N people between them - so zero for parents, 1 for grandparents, etc. That way, Jill and Jack would be from the same generation from having Lisa as an ancestor with level 2. Jack and Phil would be from the same generation from having the same parents.

Comment: @vmg, that might be not enough (it depends what `same_generation` means). For example, Rob and Mary are in the same generation, but they don't have a common ancestor.

Comment: Yes, but I was going by the OP's statement that 'same generation would essentially be a sibling or a cousin', which seems to imply that only 'same generation on the same family' is intended. Thanks for pointing it out though, hope OP sees this and considers whether he needs to account for spouses etc.

Comment: I agree if brothers-in-law and cousins-in-law are not included.

Comment: Anyway, your solution works in that case too, but it needs to explore the graph a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the same generation as those people sharing the same grandparents.